# pretty print JSON response to the console from powershell v2?

Tags: .net, json, web-services, powershell, powershell-2.0

Basic sort of [get](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49559386/262852) request:

```
thufir >
thufir >
thufir > $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.8762
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1


thufir >
thufir > type .\foo.ps1

"start"

$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://ipinfo.io/json")
$request.Method = "GET"
[System.Net.WebResponse]$response = $request.GetResponse()

$response

"done"

thufir >
thufir > .\foo.ps1
start


IsMutuallyAuthenticated : False
Cookies                 : {}
Headers                 : {Vary, x-cloud-trace-context, Access-Control-Allow-Or
                          igin, X-Content-Type-Options...}
ContentLength           : 173
ContentEncoding         :
ContentType             : application/json; charset=utf-8
CharacterSet            : utf-8
Server                  :
LastModified            : 29/03/2018 7:54:31 AM
StatusCode              : OK
StatusDescription       : OK
ProtocolVersion         : 1.1
ResponseUri             : http://ipinfo.io/json
Method                  : GET
IsFromCache             : False

done


thufir >
thufir >
```

how do I output raw JSON?  Or formatted?

Comment: Define "usable"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `WebClient` to download the JSON as a string:

```
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$json = $wc.DownloadString("http://ipinfo.io/json")
```

To use WebResponse, you would need ex. a `StreamReader` to read the response. Ex:

```
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://ipinfo.io/json")
#GET is default
#$request.Method = "GET"
$response = $request.GetResponse()
$reader = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList $response.GetResponseStream(), $response.CharacterSet

#Get JSON response
$JSON = $reader.ReadToEnd()

#Cleanup
$reader.Close()
$response.Close()
```

Comment: sometimes i still prefer this method to invoke-webrequest.

Comment: I agree. `Invoke-WebRequest` is awesome at parsing though.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the raw response as follows

```
(Invoke-WebRequest http://ipinfo.io/json ).rawcontent
```

Or parse the JSON and then select the properties that you are interested in:

```
Invoke-WebRequest http://ipinfo.io/json | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Comment: ah, I don't have `Invoke-WebRequest` unfortunately.  powershell v2.  How can I get raw response from v2?

Comment: PowerShell v2 has been deprecated. You should update